# Mysql select another table if column not exist

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create XML from my DB. The Data is in different Tables saved. Thats why I want to select from different tables columns if is not existing in the table.

How can I write the Select to check if tables has the columns I need?

```
$sql = "SELECT products_quantity FROM ".$config['table_name'], $config['table_name2'].products_description;
```

This is the complete Code

```
<?php
//database configuration
$config['mysql_host'] = "localhost";
$config['mysql_user'] = "root";
$config['mysql_pass'] = "root";
$config['db_name']    = "sqltoxml";
$config['table_name'] = "products";
$config['table_name2'] = "products_description";


//connect to host
mysql_connect($config['mysql_host'],$config['mysql_user'],$config['mysql_pass']);
//select database
@mysql_select_db($config['db_name']) or die( "Unable to select database");

$xml          = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
$root_element = $config['table_name']."s";
$xml         .= "<$root_element>";

//select all items in table
$sql = "SELECT products_id FROM ".$config['table_name'], products_description FROM ".$config['table_name2'];


$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
   while($result_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
      $xml .= "<".$config['table_name'].">";

      //loop through each key,value pair in row
      foreach($result_array as $key => $value)
      {
         //$key holds the table column name
         $xml .= "<$key>";

         //embed the SQL data in a CDATA element to avoid XML entity issues
         $xml .= "<![CDATA[$value]]>";

         //and close the element
         $xml .= "</$key>";
      }

      $xml.="</".$config['table_name'].">";
   }
}

    //close the root element
$xml .= "</$root_element>";

//send the xml header to the browser
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");

//output the XML data
echo $xml;

$fn=  "export.xml";
$fp = fopen($fn,"wb");
$write = fwrite($fp,$xml);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the schema of the two tables? If table2 has a reference to product ID in table1, you can join the two tables. Utilize an IF to specify to return one field if it contains a value, or oterhwise another.

```
SELECT IF(table1.product_quantity,table1.product_quantity,table2.product_description)
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.prodct_id;
```

This is a way in that relational databases work to allow the user to fetch data from multiple tables. There must be some match (on a column) to indicate that you'd like to recall a row from another table that is related to a row on the first table, unless other match criteria is provided.